# Empty Serialised Response in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model, a view and a serializer which produce the following response representing a medical test:

```
{
    "name": "electrocardiogram",
    "cost": "180.00",
    "results": [
        {
            "id": "bff25813-5846-4eac-812f-7e57d8fbb496",
            "lots more things" : "were here, but I hid them for brevity's sake"
            "video": []
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, it is a nested object which is put together by some nested DRF serializers.

This is great, but I want to put a couple of custom database calls into my view logic as I want to keep track of which tests a user runs. To do this I have written.

```py
class RunTestView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = TestSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        if 'test' not in self.request.query_params:
            return Response({'Error': 'test not in request'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        test = get_object_or_404(Test, id=self.request.query_params['test'])
        return test

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'case_attempt' not in request.query_params:
            return Response({'Error': 'case_attempt not in request'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        case_attempt = get_object_or_404(CaseAttempt, id=request.query_params['case_attempt'])

        # get the test object which we will later serialise and return
        test = self.get_object()

        # if we've gotten this far, both case_attempt and test are valid objects
        # let's record this in the TestsRunTracking model if it is not already there
        if not TestsRunTracking.objects.all().filter(case_attempt=case_attempt, test=test, user=request.user).exists():
            tracking = TestsRunTracking(case_attempt=case_attempt, test=test, user=request.user)
            tracking.save()

        # serialize and return the Test response
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=test)

        try:
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=False)
        except Http404:
            raise Http404

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The above code will return:

````
{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got Test."
    ]
}
```. Very dull indeed.
I can of course call the serializer with something like:
```python
serializer = self.get_serializer(data=test.__dict__)
````

But that doesn't return the related objects, just the parent object:

```
{
    "name": "electrocardiogram",
    "cost": "180.00",
}
```

I've followed the Django Rest Framework source code, and it looks as if they do exactly what I'm doing (clearly not, as DRF actually works!), but I'm clearly missing something.

So, in summary, I'm trying to return the `Test` object in my `get()` response and have it returned as shown at the top of this post, with related fields and all.

Any help is much appreciated.

Cheers,

C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `TestSerializer` is an instance of `BaseSerializer` (`rest_framework.serializers.BaseSerializer`) and you have not overridden the initializer, the `data` argument to the serializer initializer is meant to used in *deserialization* i.e. when you're handling incoming data (and creating object(s) if needed) e.g. in case of POST/PUT/PATCH. But you're doing *serialization* of an instance in `retrieve` (GET on an object URL).

You can either pass the instance `test` as a positional argument:

```
serializer = self.get_serializer(test)
```

or as a named argument being the value of name `instance`:

```
serializer = self.get_serializer(instance=test)
```

Comment: Thank you very much heemayl!

Comment: @anowlinorbit Glad, I could help :)